# Drupal - How to change the default view/edit operation Name of a content type

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am using drupal 7. First please refer my screen shot to get what i am talking about.
http://www.karya.gisla.in/scr.png

Lets say my content type is article. when we create a article, for authenticated users, the node displayes primary tabs namely : View and Edit. I just want to change/edit it to say :View Article and Edit Article.

Note: Just for a specific content type only. i.e other content type say Page will display as default : View and Edit.

Any ideas how to achieve this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code does the trick. Paste it in your themes template.php and change YOURTHEMENAME to... your theme's name.
maybe use dpm($vars) in this function to have a look which kinds of information in $vars is. This should help you getting to the point even faster next time.

[EDIT:]
Thanks Ben for pointing that out!
Here's an updated version:

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['node']->type == 'article') {
    foreach($vars['tabs']['#primary'] AS $index => $tab) {
      if($tab['#link']['title'] == t('View')) {
        $vars['tabs']['#primary'][$index]['#link']['title'] = t('View Article');
      }

      if($tab['#link']['title'] == t('Edit')) {
        $vars['tabs']['#primary'][$index]['#link']['title'] = t('Edit Article');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Have fun, Martin

Comment: This assumes that no modules have added links before View or Edit (thus changing the keys `0` and `1`) meaning that other tabs could be overwritten.

Comment: Thanks. Its worked. @ben-swinburne : You are right but for now I have no such modules.

Answer (score 0):

The [String Overrides Module](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) may help, though I'm not sure if it handles roles.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the following function into the template file of your theme and replace `YOURTHEME` with the theme name to alter the tab links.

`$nodes` is a multidimensional array in which the first level of keys are the content types you wish to replace tabs on and the second level of key value combinations are path and replacement pattern respectively. Setting a replacement pattern as `''` will remove the tab.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_local_tasks_alter().
 */
 function YOURTHEME_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $router_item, $root_path) {
    $nodes = array(
        'article'   =>  array(
            'node/%/view'   =>  'View Article',
            'node/%/edit'   =>  'Edit Article'
        )
    );

    foreach ($router_item['page_arguments'] as $key => $argument) {
        if (is_object($argument) && array_key_exists( $router_item['page_arguments'][$key]->type, $nodes )) {
            foreach( $nodes[$router_item['page_arguments'][$key]->type] as $path => $new_title ) {
                foreach ($data['tabs'][0]['output'] as $key => $value) {
                    if ($value['#link']['path'] == $path) {
                        if( !$new_title ) {
                            unset($data['tabs'][0]['output'][$key]);
                        } else {
                            $data['tabs'][0]['output'][$key]['#link']['title'] = $new_title;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you please explain your code specially the foreach loop. As you said in the comment below "assumes that no modules have added links before View or Edit". I would love to implement it. But please could just explain me the code a bit so that I would not forget it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a module for that:
https://drupal.org/project/tabname_tweaker
;-)

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48276/change-name-of-a-tab-for-a-specific-content-type